# Formatting typographer's quote marks

Tags: formatting

This question has been asked before. But, I have not found a solution. I have a problem related with quotation marks.

A MWE is:

**main document:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,british,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{novel}
```

then,

**novel.sty:**

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

I need to be able to obtain left/right single typographer's quote marks and left/right double typographer's quote marks.

The resulting .pdf contains straight quotes that are all slanted the same way (forward). I have tried a number of ways of adding quote marks to the text with no success. Is this because of my font choice (Palatino)?

I would really appreciate help in obtaining curly typographer's quote marks. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

---

Again, thanks for your interest. Here is my MWE.

**The main .tex file is:**

```
%TITR Main Document 5.06in x 7.81in, facing pages
%Preamble
\documentclass[10pt,english,british,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{novel}

%Frontmatter
\begin{document}
    \title{Tears in the Rain}
    \date{}
    \maketitle
\frontmatter
    \pagestyle{empty} %Empty page left
    \noindent \begin{flushright}
    {\huge{}Tears in the Rain}
    \par\end{flushright}{\huge \par}
    \cleardoubleoddemptypage
    \thispagestyle {empty}
    \includegraphics{./images/bensig}
    \vspace*{0.5in}
    \begin{flushright}

    {\Huge{}Tears in the Rain}
    \par\end{flushright}{\Huge \par}

%Add an empty page and Copyright material.
    \clearpage
    \begin{center}
    \emph{Copyright}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \textcopyright{ 2014 Ben Francis All rights reserved.}
    \end{center}

\vspace*{0.5in}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\paperwidth}
    No part of this publication may be reproduced, stored
    in a retrieval system, or transmitted in any form, or by any means;
    mechanical, electrical, photocopying, scanning, recording or otherwise,
    without prior written consent from the publishers. Every effort has
    been made to contact all copyright holders. The author and publisher
    will gladly rectify any omissions.
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.5in}
\begin{center}
    ISBN:
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.2in}
\begin{center}
    A CIP Record for this book is available from the British
    Library.
\end{center}

\vspace*{0.1in}

\begin{center}
    Typeset in \LaTeXe
\end{center}

%Insert an empty left page
\cleardoubleoddemptypage 
\thispagestyle {empty} 
\vspace*{\fill}

%Table of Contents
\tableofcontents

\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Preface}}{} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}

\chapter*{Preface}
\input{./chapters/a_front/pref.tex}
%\subfile{./chapters/a_front/pref.tex}

%Mainmatter
\mainmatter
\noindent

%The header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\tiny \slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\tiny \slshape Ben Francis}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small \slshape \thepage \hspace{3mm} Tears in the Rain}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\small \slshape Tears in the Rain}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\small \slshape Tears in the Rain}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.25pt}

%The Chapters
\input{./child_docs/child_docs.tex}

\end{document}
```

**This calls 'novel.sty':**

```
%novel.sty (Style package for the novel template)
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.1}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ppl}
\newcommand{\apostrophe}{\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXcharglyph"0027\relax}
\KOMAoptions{open=any}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ppl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}

%Settings for quotation marks<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage[autostyle, english = british]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

%Settings for page size and layout >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.06in,paperheight=7.81in]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0.5in,bmargin=1in,inner=0.75in,outer=0.5in,headheight=0.1in,headsep=0.15in,footskip=0.45in,twoside}

%Character dialogue settings >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
\newlist{dialogdash}{description}{1}
\setlist[dialogdash]{labelindent = 0.25in, leftmargin = \labelindent, labelsep = 0.3em, rightmargin = 0.35in, nosep,topsep = 0.5ex, itemsep = 0.5ex, align = left}
\newenvironment{dlgdash}{\begin{dialogdash}\item[---]}{\end{dialogdash}}
\newlist{dialognodash}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[dialognodash]{label = ,labelindent = 0.25in, leftmargin = \labelindent, rightmargin = 0.35in, nosep, topsep = 0.1ex, itemsep = 0.1ex, align = left} 
\newenvironment{dlgnodash}{\begin{dialognodash}\item }{\end{dialognodash}}
\def\bdlg{\begin{dlgnodash}}
\def\edlg{\end{dlgnodash}}
%End Dialogue settings <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

**And finally, the 'child_docs.tex' file**:

```
\input{./chapters/part_one/part_one.tex}

\chapter{One}
    \input{./chapters/chap_one/scenes/one_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_one/scenes/one_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_one/scenes/one_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_one/scenes/one_four.tex}

\chapter{Two}
    \input{./chapters/chap_two/scenes/two_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_two/scenes/two_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_two/scenes/two_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_two/scenes/two_four.tex}

    \chapter{Three}
    \input{./chapters/chap_three/scenes/three_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_three/scenes/three_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_three/scenes/three_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_three/scenes/three_four.tex}

 \input{./chapters/part_two/part_two.tex}

    \chapter{Four}
    \input{./chapters/chap_four/scenes/four_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_four/scenes/four_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_four/scenes/four_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_four/scenes/four_four.tex}

    \chapter{Five}
    \input{./chapters/chap_five/scenes/five_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_five/scenes/five_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_five/scenes/five_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_five/scenes/five_four.tex}

    \chapter{Six}
    \input{./chapters/chap_six/scenes/six_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_six/scenes/six_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_six/scenes/six_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_six/scenes/six_four.tex}

    \input{./chapters/part_three/part_three.tex}

    \chapter{Seven}
    \input{./chapters/chap_seven/scenes/seven_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_seven/scenes/seven_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_seven/scenes/seven_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_seven/scenes/seven_four.tex}

    \chapter{Eight}
    \input{./chapters/chap_eight/scenes/eight_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_eight/scenes/eight_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_eight/scenes/eight_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_eight/scenes/eight_four.tex}

    \chapter{Nine}
    \input{./chapters/chap_nine/scenes/nine_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_nine/scenes/nine_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_nine/scenes/nine_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_nine/scenes/nine_four.tex}

    \input{./chapters/part_four/part_four.tex}

    \chapter{Ten}
    \input{./chapters/chap_ten/scenes/ten_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_ten/scenes/ten_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_ten/scenes/ten_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_ten/scenes/ten_four.tex}

    \chapter{Eleven}
    \input{./chapters/chap_eleven/scenes/eleven_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_eleven/scenes/eleven_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_eleven/scenes/eleven_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_eleven/scenes/eleven_four.tex}

    \chapter{Twelve}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twelve/scenes/twelve_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twelve/scenes/twelve_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twelve/scenes/twelve_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twelve/scenes/twelve_four.tex}

    \chapter{Thirteen}
    \input{./chapters/chap_thirteen/scenes/thirteen_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_thirteen/scenes/thirteen_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_thirteen/scenes/thirteen_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_thirteen/scenes/thirteen_four.tex}

    \input{./chapters/part_five/part_five.tex}

    \chapter{Fourteen}
    \input{./chapters/chap_fourteen/scenes/fourteen_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_fourteen/scenes/fourteen_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_fourteen/scenes/fourteen_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_fourteen/scenes/fourteen_four.tex}

    \chapter{Fifteen}
    \input{./chapters/chap_fifteen/scenes/fifteen_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_fifteen/scenes/fifteen_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_fifteen/scenes/fifteen_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_fifteen/scenes/fifteen_four.tex}

    \chapter{Sixteen}
    \input{./chapters/chap_sixteen/scenes/sixteen_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_sixteen/scenes/sixteen_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_sixteen/scenes/sixteen_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_sixteen/scenes/sixteen_four.tex}

    \input{./chapters/part_six/part_six.tex}

    \chapter{Seventeen}
    \input{./chapters/chap_seventeen/scenes/seventeen_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_seventeen/scenes/seventeen_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_seventeen/scenes/seventeen_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_seventeen/scenes/seventeen_four.tex}

    \chapter{Eighteen}
    \input{./chapters/chap_eighteen/scenes/eighteen_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_eighteen/scenes/eighteen_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_eighteen/scenes/eighteen_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_eighteen/scenes/eighteen_four.tex}

    \chapter{Nineteen}
    \input{./chapters/chap_nineteen/scenes/nineteen_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_nineteen/scenes/nineteen_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_nineteen/scenes/nineteen_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_nineteen/scenes/nineteen_four.tex}

    \input{./chapters/part_seven/part_seven.tex}

    \chapter{Twenty}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twenty/scenes/twenty_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twenty/scenes/twenty_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twenty/scenes/twenty_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twenty/scenes/twenty_four.tex}

    \chapter{Twenty-One}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentyone/scenes/twentyone_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentyone/scenes/twentyone_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentyone/scenes/twentyone_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentyone/scenes/twentyone_four.tex}

    \chapter{Twenty-Two}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentytwo/scenes/twentytwo_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentytwo/scenes/twentytwo_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentytwo/scenes/twentytwo_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentytwo/scenes/twentytwo_four.tex}

    \chapter{Twenty-Three}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentythree/scenes/twentythree_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentythree/scenes/twentythree_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentythree/scenes/twentythree_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentythree/scenes/twentythree_four.tex}

    \chapter{Twenty-Four}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentyfour/scenes/twentyfour_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentyfour/scenes/twentyfour_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentyfour/scenes/twentyfour_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentyfour/scenes/twentyfour_four.tex}

    \chapter{Twenty-Five}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentyfive/scenes/twentyfive_one.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentyfive/scenes/twentyfive_two.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentyfive/scenes/twentyfive_three.tex}
    \input{./chapters/chap_twentyfive/scenes/twentyfive_four.tex}

    \chapter*{Meet the Author}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Meet the Author}
    \input{./chapters/d_back/back.tex}
```

Comment: Did you type typographers quote marks in your editor(using UTF8 input encoding and T1 font encoding)?

Comment: When in doubt, make a minimal working example :-) If I do `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
``Hello''
\end{document}` I get what I'd expect: 'straight-ish' quotes as that is the style in Palatino. We've not got a full MWE in the question at present, but I suspect you could well be right that this is simply a font design situation.

Comment: Have you tried the `enquote` command `csquotes` provides?

Comment: Yes, I've tried "\enquote" and the quotation marks stay the same (forward slanted). Using ``nmnm'' produces the same output. This is my "novel.sty" includes
\usepackage{palatino} %set font globally
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = british]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

Comment: @Mike We need a add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also note that you can add code by editing your question - don't add it as a comment since it is unreadable. That said, why are you loading a whole bunch of incompatible font packages. You are not setting palatino globally if you then set EB Garamond globally and then set Latin Modern globally and then... Are you sure you can use `"` as an active quote character?

Comment: I've converted the 'answer' to an edit, but this is far from a MWE. Please take a look at the link @cfr gave about preparing one: cut down your input to something we can test (probably running everything into one file).

Comment: Also, as I've already noted, Palatino has 'straight' looking quotes as a design decision, so if you are choosing that font then you don't get the more 'curly' style of quote some fonts provide.

Comment: @JosephWright Could that last comment of yours be an answer, or close as unclear?

Comment: @JosephWright In agreement with Torbjørn. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You're loading several useless font packages: you have

```
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{type1cm}
```

`palatino` is obsolete; `ebgaramond` voids the action of `palatino`; `lmodern` voids the action of `ebgaramond`; `mathpazo` voids the action of `lmodern`.

Next `type1cm` defines some font families that will never be used.

However you also have the line

```
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ppl}
```

which voids most actions of `mathpazo`. You eventually get Palatino, but almost by chance (and in the wrong family).

If you want Palatino as the main font, just use

```
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
```

or

```
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
```

and ***no*** `\renewcommand\rmdefault{...}` command. Leave this to the chosen font package.

About the “issue” with “typographic quotes”, there is just one thing to do: the quotes of Palatino have been designed by Hermann Zapf in a rather peculiar way: the input

```
``quotes''

\bigskip

"quotes"
```

(with your definition of `\MakeOuterQuote`) produces

[image]

which agrees with the quotes as designed by Zapf.